# wxWidgets linking problem

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, wxwidgets

I installed  wxWidgets-2.8.10 following instructions from this page:
http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_and_getting_started

Libraries directory:

```
alex@alex-linux:/usr/local/lib$ ls | grep wx
libwx_base-2.8.a
libwx_base_net-2.8.a
libwx_base_xml-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.a
libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.a
libwxtiff-2.8.a
wx
```

Then I created file widgetTest.cpp and filled it with this code:
http://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/hworld.txt

Trying to build it, I have a lot of linker errors:

```
alex@alex-linux:~$ cd /home/alex/Tmp
alex@alex-linux:~/Tmp$ g++ `wx-config --cppflags` `wx-config --libs` widgetTest.cpp
/tmp/ccnPCAw5.o: In function `wxCreateApp()':
widgetTest.cpp:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `wxAppConsole::CheckBuildOptions(char const*, char const*)'
/tmp/ccnPCAw5.o: In function `main':
...
widgetTest.cpp:(.text._ZN20wxThreadHelperThreadD0Ev[wxThreadHelperThread::~wxThreadHelperThread()]+0x16): undefined reference to `wxThread::~wxThread()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Additional information:

```
alex@alex-linux:~$ wx-config --cppflags
-I/usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-static-2.8 -I/usr/local/include/wx-2.8 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGE_FILES -D__WXGTK__
alex@alex-linux:~$ wx-config --libs
-L/usr/local/lib -pthread   /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.a /usr/local/lib/libwx_base-2.8.a -pthread -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -latk-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpango-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lgobject-2.0 -lgmodule-2.0 -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -lXinerama -lSM -lpng -ljpeg -lexpat -lwxtiff-2.8 -lz -ldl -lm 
alex@alex-linux:~$
```

What is wrong?

Comment: g++ `wx-config --cppflags` widgetTest.cpp `wx-config --libs`
It worked! How can I apply this solution to my working environment - Eclipse CDT. I add `wx-config --cppflags` to GCC compiler settings, and `wx-config --libs` to the linker settings, and get linker errors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does this help?

```
g++ `wx-config --cppflags` widgetTest.cpp `wx-config --libs`
```

Sometimes putting the libraries *after* the sources is required.

Comment: Yes, it is required whenever you use static linking (as the OP does). And being a direct consequence of the search algorithm used by the traditional Unix linkers it's not specific to neither wxWidgets nor Linux.

Comment: Moving the libraries to the end helped, command line build succeeded, thank you!

Now I return to my working environment: Eclipse CDT. How to reproduce this solution here? In the Compiler settings, I have Other flags: `wx-config --cppflags`, in the Linker settings, I have Other flags `wx-config --libs`. Build results linker errors.

Comment: For reference: In Eclipse CDT the problem is solved by changing linkercommand line pattern: FLAGS is moved to the end.